# Is "¿Qué dices si te rompo la cara?" a good translation of "what'd you say about me breaking your face"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

In the movie *Men in Black*, Tommy Lee Jones says this in the border patrol scene:

> ¿Qué dices si te rompo la cara?

I think it's a literal translation of:

> What'd you say about me breaking your face?

This sentence is fine in English, but was curious if such an expression does exist in Spanish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The entry for [cara](https://dle.rae.es/cara) in DLE includes no less than three expressions with a similar meaning:

> [**cruzarle la cara** a alguien](https://dle.rae.es/cara#AanVDaV)
>
> 1. loc. verb. Darle en ella una bofetada, un latigazo, etc.
>
> [...]
>
> [**partirle** a alguien **la cara**](https://dle.rae.es/cara#Li6xf47)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Dejarlo en una pelea muy maltrecho. U. m. c. amenaza.
>
> [...]
>
> [**romperle la cara** a alguien](https://dle.rae.es/cara#EygWci9)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. partirle la cara.

So yes, you can say either **partir la cara** or **romper la cara** to mean "hurt someone badly".

Comment: Pero te suena natural en combinación con "que dices si"? No soy nativo, pero algo me suena raro con _que dices si te rompo la cara_. No necesita un subjuntivo por algún lado allí? ¿Algo tipo _Que dirías si te rompe la cara_?

Comment: @terdon no es lo más natural para mí,  pero tampoco me sorprendería. La forma más natural para mí sería "¿Y qué tal si te rompo la cara?". La construcción condicional "¿Y qué dirías si te rompo la cara?" podría estar bien, y sería algo menos directa. La construcción subjuntiva "¿Y qué dirías si te rompiera la cara?" suena peor porque pierde el tono de amenaza directa.

Comment: ¿ *qué dirías si te rompo* y no si te _rompe_? Uf, ¡nunca conseguiré controlar el subjuntivo! Gracias :).

Comment: @terdon "yo rompo" es presente de indicativo. "yo rompiera" es pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo. "Yo rompa" es presente de subjuntivo, pero el presente de subjuntivo no se utiliza para construir frases condicionales. "Rompe" es tercera persona: "él rompe".

Comment: Argh, esto si que lo sabía. Perdón, quería decir _si te rompa_. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @terdon en este contexto, a mí me sonaría mucho mejor _A que te rompo la cara_. La parte inicial de "¿Qué dices...?" no me suena nada natural. No sé si la expresión original inglesa también usa esta perífrasis o va más al grano.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly fine grammatically but I don't know if it sounds as natural as it does in English. In Argentina I would rather expect "¿Y si te rompo la cara?" (which is short for "¿Y [qué pasaría] si te rompo la cara?" -> "What would happen/what would you do about me breaking your face?")

Comment: It sounds like "whaddaya say I break your face?" To me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the actual phrase works although obviously ''Que dices si te rompo la cara?' sounds a bit strange without the context of a strong argument or disagreement.  To be honest, it also sounds strange even in English to me as
a native speaker without a lot of context which the film presumably provides.

On page 30 of *La ciudad y los perros* (a famous Spanish-language novel by Mario Vargas Llosa), one finds the following exchange:

> Alberto siente que Vallano camina de puntillas.  Después, oye un ruido revelador.

> -- Se están robando un cordón -grita.

> -- Un día de estos **te voy a romper la cara**, poeta -dice Vallano, bostezando.

Comment: It's pretty common in everyday street talk type things...

Comment: I'm just saying it sounds a bit strange and violent.  I'm sure people do actually say it on the street though.